# Google Maps Api button for "route to marker" / go to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes

I'd like to know if it is possible to have a button on a Google Map that redirects you to Google Maps, submitting the destination address, so that the user just needs to enter his/her own address to calculate the route.

Edit: If there is a method to directly implement a custom button with a simple link (that leads to the shared map on Google) that would work just as fine as well.

Edit 2: Managed to solve it myself with the help of the google doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom

took a lot of js fiddling around but it works now

Comment: Could you post your complete solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the example from the Google Maps Documentation for future reference. Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom

```js
var map;
var chicago = {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65};

/**
 * The CenterControl adds a control to the map that recenters the map on
 * Chicago.
 * This constructor takes the control DIV as an argument.
 * @constructor
 */
function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.textContent = 'Center Map';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
  controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago);
  });

}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: chicago
  });

  // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the CenterControl()
  // constructor passing in this DIV.
  var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);

  centerControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The target-URL would be:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir//{encodedAddress}
```

Note the 2 slashes after dir, when you use 1 slash the address would be used as start-address. The address must be encoded (e.g. via `encodeURIComponent`)

Sample-button(uses his `textContent` as address):

```
<button onclick="top.window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/dir//'+
                                  encodeURIComponent(this.textContent.trim()),
                                 'gmap')">
    Berlin
</button>
```

Comment: hmm in that case I could simply create a link that looks like a button with `target="_blank"`, but I would like to have that as part of the map controls

Comment: then add the button to the controls, any HTMLElement may be a control

Comment: Nice! but how to add that custom button to Google Maps API v3 (JavaScript)? I'm to figure out the appearance of the actual embed iframes generated by Google Maps.